# How to change name server in GoDaddy may hosting in hostinger

Tags: php

I want change name server in GoDaddy my hosting on hostinger vps hosting and my control panel is cent os control panel where I get me name server

Answer (score 0):

You should get your Name server on Email when you order the Hosting server also you can find the name server on logged in cpanel.